# How to extrapolate specific data recalled through the id of a json file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Given the response of a JSON file:

```json
{
    "Response": [
        {
            "ResultCode": "000",
            "ResultMessage": "OK",
            "NRecord": "2",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "nomepacchetto": "Nome Pacchetto",
                    "tipotraffico": "C",
                    "numerominuti": "100.00000",
                    "importocanone": "9.99",
                    "loginultimamodifica": "claudia.mentuccia",
                    "dataorainiziovalidita": "2022-04-28 14:10:01",
                    "loginapprovazione": "",
                    "dataapprovazione": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "id": "4"
                },
                {
                    "nomepacchetto": "Nome Pacchetto_2",
                    "tipotraffico": "C",
                    "numerominuti": "10.00000",
                    "importocanone": "5.00",
                    "loginultimamodifica": "claudia.mentuccia",
                    "dataorainiziovalidita": "2022-04-28 14:11:29",
                    "loginapprovazione": "",
                    "dataapprovazione": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                    "id": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I retrieve all identifying data by id through JavaScript?

```js
function StampaForm() {
   var TblContenuto;
   var TblContenuto = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.wbc_gestionepacchetti800_applicazione);
   var form = "<form action=\"wbc_gestionepacchetti800_3.html\" name='dati' method=\"post\"><div class='tabella_select'><tbody class='body_form'><table class='table table-responsive-sm'>";
   var output = '';
   var output = '<tr>' + '<td class="campi_form col-2 td_body">' + '<p>Nome pacchetto\n</p>' + ' <input type=text class="form-control recordripreso" id="floatingInput" name=nuovoip size=40 value="' + TblContenuto[i].nomepacchetto + '">' + '</td>' + '<td></td>' + '<tr>';
   $("#mod").append(form + output);
}
```

The variable `var TblContenuto = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.wbc_gestionepacchetti800_applicazione);` shows all the contents of my JSON file (above), what I would like to do is create a function that extrapolates the data fragment based on the ID, example:
id = 5:

```js
{
  "nomepacchetto": "Nome Pacchetto_2",
  "tipotraffico": "C",
  "numerominuti": "10.00000",
  "importocanone": "5.00",
  "loginultimamodifica": "claudia.mentuccia",
  "dataorainiziovalidita": "2022-04-28 14:11:29",
  "loginapprovazione": "",
  "dataapprovazione": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
   "id": "5"
 }
```

Comment: Please keep the question entirely in English.

Comment: Done, I changed the question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I don't dislike it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also do this (avoid to add all element one by one) and gives you the JSON (the code is below the json variable, used for test) :

```js
var json='{ \
    "Response": [ \
        { \
            "ResultCode": "000", \
            "ResultMessage": "OK", \
            "NRecord": "2", \
            "Details": [ \
                { \
                    "nomepacchetto": "Nome Pacchetto", \
                    "tipotraffico": "C", \
                    "numerominuti": "100.00000", \
                    "importocanone": "9.99", \
                    "loginultimamodifica": "claudia.mentuccia", \
                    "dataorainiziovalidita": "2022-04-28 14:10:01", \
                    "loginapprovazione": "", \
                    "dataapprovazione": "0000-00-00 00:00:00", \
                    "id": "4" \
                }, \
                { \
                    "nomepacchetto": "Nome Pacchetto_2", \
                    "tipotraffico": "C", \
                    "numerominuti": "10.00000", \
                    "importocanone": "5.00", \
                    "loginultimamodifica": "claudia.mentuccia", \
                    "dataorainiziovalidita": "2022-04-28 14:11:29", \
                    "loginapprovazione": "", \
                    "dataapprovazione": "0000-00-00 00:00:00", \
                    "id": "5" \
                } \
            ] \
        } \
    ] \
}';
test=JSON.parse(json);
response=test.Response;
response[0].Details.forEach(function(element ) {
    if (element["id"]=="5") { //Change this value to get the id you want
    $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(element)); //Remove function to have the variable (element)
    $.each(element, function(key, value) {
      $("#calc").append("Key :",key,"  Value:",value,"<br/>");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="calc">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me, that's so kind of you,
the script works!
is it possible instead to write all the data inside the file by hand and create a dynamic thing?

Comment: Sure, as long as your variable is JSON-like, you can get it from any sources (file, website requests, php...).

Comment: Hi @JoelCrypto , I can't transform that variable of yours 'json' dynamically, i.e. set the declared variable as you put it, everything works correctly with my array variable `var TblContenuto = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.wbc_gestionepacchetti800_applicazione);` it doesn't work, could you help me?

Comment: Does your variable looks the same way as the array above? Where did you put this code?

Comment: You dont have anymore response or details so remove this part.